# Why can browsers on mobile devices play videos with resolutions higher than the device supports, but native apps displaying the same web app may fail?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, html5-video

I work on a project that uses a native android/iOS app to display a webview for the web app I work on. Ensuring video playback on various devices is a large pain point that I've had to work through for years. I've managed to support essentially any device by transcoding videos to lower bitrates, lower resolutions, and/or other codecs that are best fit for said device/browser, but I've never understood why the videos that fail to play in my web app from inside of our native app's webview have this issue, while running my web app inside a browser on the device is able to play back videos fine regardless of codec, resolution, or bitrate. (assuming the browser supports the format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview included in Android devices differs between devices and between Android versions, which can be a problem for support of low level functionality like video playback as you have seen.

There is a nice overview here - it is a little old now but the link is still live at time of writing:

- http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/42

They have a nice TL/DR:

> THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS
> "THE" ANDROID BROWSER

Comment: That was an informative and funny slide deck, thanks for sharing!